# Magento objects not executing while login thru drupal

Tags: magento, drupal

I am trying to make a single sign on with drupal and magento

I run this code from a separate php file it logs in to magento perfectly

```
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/mage1/app/Mage.php";
      umask(0);
      Mage::App('default');

      $session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));
      try {
        $session->login($row['mail'], $row['field_magentopass_value']);

        $session->setCustomerAsLoggedIn($session->getCustomer());
 } catch (Exception $e) {
        print_r($e);
        exit;
      }
```

But when i run this code from Drupal it will not sign into magento and it will singout from Drupal as well

I user hook_user_login to run the above code.

But on the other hand i am able to register as magento customers while somebody sign up with drupal following the same conventions

can anybody tell what is the problem here

Following is the Druapl 7 cookie info after a user is logged in

```
Array
(
    [Drupal_tableDrag_showWeight] => 0
    [Drupal_toolbar_collapsed] => 0
    [has_js] => 1
    [SESSe314d96b48831bb642879451688dbfdc] => Km3_IJoagTatwjw2orgimZ6-UwtgFF0WCTtl6fEDDAw
)
```

with out login

```
 Array
    (
        [Drupal_tableDrag_showWeight] => 0
        [Drupal_toolbar_collapsed] => 0
        [has_js] => 1

    )
```

Comment: I have no knowledge of drupal, but I guess it may be overwriting drupal cookie

Comment: i am editing the question with drupal cookie info after login

Comment: @Nasaralla: is my question clear now?